# Can not import SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Found my old project, but can't import SQL file cause haven't worked with it for a few years. What do these letters and numbers say to me? What is wrong with `pubdate`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try current_date instead, as default value.

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis for the DEFAULT value with DATE

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (i int,
>   ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>    d1 DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 (i) VALUES(1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
>  i | ts                  | dt                  | d1        
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :---------
>  1 | 2021-11-17 21:24:32 | 2021-11-17 21:24:32 | 2021-11-17
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=826f8ca2bdb25d365e4fb11069ad89b5)*